# Como extraer y comparar los valores de un objeto guardado en un array? Java

Tags: java

Tengo un `ArrayList` de clientes y tengo que encontrar un cliente por nombre y comparar su deuda con otra valor para saber si puede comprar o no. Este es mi codigo. Me dice que el metodo.getNombre no esta definido y que no puede resolver DEUDA. Alguien me orientaria un poco sobre como hacer esto bien?
Gracias y saludos!

```
public void generarFactura(int IMPORTE){        
    String NOMBRECLIENTE;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Inserte el nombre del cliente que desea hacer una compra");
    NOMBRECLIENTE= sc.nextLine();

    //aca recorreria el arraylist y verificaria que el cliente este, y que su deuda sea 
    //menor a 4000$ para ahi pasar a emitir factura
    int i=0;

    for (i=0;i<((CharSequence) listaClientes).length();i++) {

        if (listaClientes.getNombre().equals(NOMBRECLIENTE)){

            if(listaClientes.DEUDA<4000){
                    //creo el objeto factura y le doy valores random
                    Factura facturacliente=new Factura(3000, 7, 8);
        }else{
            System.out.println("El cliente acumulo demasiada deuda");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: que es listaClientes? debe ser una clase no? o eso espero? o mejor deberia ser una lista que contenga la clase clientes no? entonces no deberias acceder a listaclientes[i].GetNombre?

Comment: listaClientes es un ArrayList de objetos.

Comment: entonces debes acceder a cada item de la lista.. la lista entera no tiene el metodo getNombre

Comment: Claro, entiendo. Como puedo acceder a cada item en orden? hay alguna funcion que haga eso?

Comment: Tienes esto `i<((CharSequence) listaClientes).length()`. Sin embargo, si has declarado listaClientes así: `List<Cliente> listaClientes = new LinkedList<>();` y luego quieres obtener un miembro de la lista, podrías hacer `listaClientes.get(i).getNombre();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumo que listaClientes es algo como:

```
ArrayList<Cliente> listaClientes;
```

Por tanto, quieres recorrer la lista y encontrar el cliente puedes hacerlo así:

```
for (Cliente c: listaClientes) {
    if (c.getNombre().equals(...)) {

    }
}
```

o así:

```
for (int i=0; i< listaClientes.size(); i++) {
    Cliente c= listaClientes.get(i);
    if (c.getNombre().equals(...)) {

    }
}
```

o así:

```
listaClientes.forEach(cliente -> {
    if (cliente.getNombre().equals(...) {

    }
);
```

Comment: Gracias! No encontraba puntualmente como aplicar esto y me estaba volviendo loco.

Comment: De nada :) Puedes votar las respuestas que te sean útiles y marcar como aceptada alguna de ellas, para que la pregunta quede como "respondida".

Comment: Te falto usar iterator no mas xD

Answer (score 0):

Deberías hacer entonces:

```
listaClientes.get(i).getNombre().equals(NOMBRECLIENTE);
```

No puedes aplicar el método getNombre() a la lista completa, sino a cada miembro. Es decir no puedes hacer esto:

```
listaClientes.getNombre()
```

Aquí te pasa lo mismo:

```
if(listaClientes.DEUDA<4000){
                    //creo el objeto factura y le doy valores random
                    Factura facturacliente=new Factura(3000, 7, 8);
```

Debería ser:

```
 if(listaClientes.get(i).DEUDA<4000){
                    //creo el objeto factura y le doy valores random
                    Factura facturacliente=new Factura(3000, 7, 8);
```

Comment: Creo que te has liado con el orden de los métodos, sería `get(i).getNombre()`

Comment: Gracias, lo he corregido. Ya lo había puesto en el último comentario :-)

Comment: Gracias a los 2! Me sirvio muchisimo.